# Best unit test framework for Angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, protractor

I need to start unit testing for my angularjs app, I am a bit confused with, which is best framework out of Protractor or Jasmine.

Majorly I need to test controller functions, services, dependency injection, state data.

Please suggest which one to go for.

You can suggest any other better framework also apart from these two.